# getting Gmail rss without login

Tags: rss, authentication

I want to display emails using google rss feed. The link for this purpose is https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom. But this links require authentication.

I want to create an link after first time login which is used to get the rss feeds. The link can be used any time to get the rss it will not ask for authentication again.

Let me know, how can I do this. Means I want to generate a link which is always used to get the emails in rss format. This link is generated on first login.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET I do it this way - works fine:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver { Credentials = credentials };
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings { XmlResolver = resolver };
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom", settings);
XDocument document1 = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this URL format: [https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom](https://USERNAME%3aPASSWORD@gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom)